# Why is $X_m$ and $Y_m$ not included in the shaded region(where median can lie)?

Tags: algorithms, recursion, divide-and-conquer

This problem is from  [Algorithms](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~kalpakis/courses/441-sp03/hws/hw4-sol.pdf), problem 2

**The Problem** Given two sorted list of numbers $X$[1..$n$] and $Y$[1..n]. we need to come up with a O($log n$) time algorithm to find the median of the 2$n$ lists.'

My question is regarding the case where median($X$) is less than the median($Y$).

Here is the proof that the authors(gave) that any element in $X$ less than median($X$) cannot be the median of the two lists.

1. Suppose an element e is in $A$ and e $\lt$ median($X$). Then there will be less than $\frac12n$ elements less than e(in $X$)
2. Since e $\lt$ median($X$) $\lt$ median($Y$) there are less than $\frac12n$ elements less than e(in $B$)

Because of 1 and 2, the median cannot be any element in $A$ that is less than median($A$)

I agree with every step in the proof and with that statement. However, here is the diagram of possibilities where the median of the two lists can be

[image]

Based off that proof, I understand why all the elements  below the median of $A$ and in $A$ cannot be the median of the two lists. But what justification did author use to eliminate median($X$) as a possibility? It wasn't included in the shaded region.

Answer (score 4):

$X_m$ and $Y_m$ are not shaded, because each of them *is* potentially the median of $X \cup Y$.

Consider two examples (Below I take the $\lfloor (n+1)/2 \rfloor$-th element as the median of an array of size $n$):

(1) $X = \{ 2, 4, 6 \}$ and $Y = \{ 3, 5, 7 \}$.

(2) $X = \{ 2, 4, 6 , 8 \}$ and $Y = \{ 3, 5, 7, 9 \}$.

I think the caption of Figure 1 is wrong: median of two sorted lists lies in the **unshaded** region.

Comment: I agree each of them is potentially the median. But in the diagram, the shaded region is where the median could lie so it should be shaded. That's what I was confused about

Comment: @committedandroider I think the caption of Figure 1 is wrong: median of two sorted lists lies in the **unshaded** region.